# Как в pandas разделить строку на несколько по разделителю

Tags: python, pandas, list

Есть датафрейм pandas из одного столбца. В каждой ячейке от одного до нескольких слов разделенных запятыми. Подскажите как объединить все слова в один столбец, чтобы в каждой ячейке было только одно слово?

Comment: [str.split](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) + [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для объединения слов в один столбец в каждой ячейке, вы можете использовать метод str.split() для разделения строк по запятым, а затем метод explode() для превращения списка слов в отдельные строки. Затем можно снова объединить строки с помощью метода groupby() и apply() с функцией ','.join для получения одного слова в каждой ячейке. Вот пример кода:

```
import pandas as pd

# Пример исходного датафрейма с одним столбцом
data = {'words': ['apple,orange', 'banana', 'grape,kiwi,mango', 'pear']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Разделение строк по запятым и превращение списка в отдельные строки
df['words'] = df['words'].str.split(',')

# Превращение списка слов в отдельные строки
df = df.explode('words')

# Объединение слов обратно в одну строку с помощью groupby и apply
df = df.groupby(level=0)['words'].apply(','.join).reset_index()

print(df)
```

В результате получится датафрейм, в котором в каждой ячейке будет только одно слово:

```
   index   words
0      0   apple
1      1  orange
2      2  banana
3      3   grape
4      3    kiwi
5      3   mango
6      4    pear
```